# For all subspaces $B$ of normed spaces $A$ there exista $a\in A$ s.t. $||a||=1$ and $d(a,B)=\inf_{b\in B}||a-b||>1-\epsilon$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be normed vector space, and $B\subsetneq A$ a linear subspace that is *not* necessarily closed. Let $\epsilon>0$.

> There exists a $a\in A$ s.t. $||a||=1$ and $d(a,B)=\inf_{b\in B}||a-b||>1-\epsilon$.

Is this statement true or false? My intuition says false, but I would have no idea how to find a counter-example (or proof if it's true). Can somebody give me a hint how to start (and tell me whether it is true or false)?

Comment: First look at the subspace $\overline{B}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I know that such an $a$ exists for $d(a,\overline{B})$ by Riesz' Lemma, how would I continue?

Comment: There are two possibilities. Either $\overline{B} = A$, or $\overline{B} \subsetneqq A$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What would the consequences be of those possibilities? I tried to think what that would imply, but could not come up with anything

Comment: What do you know about the relation between $d(a,B)$ and $d(a,\overline{B})$?

Comment: @DanielFischer $d(a,B)\geq d(a,\overline{B})$?

Comment: That's true. But can you say something stronger even?

Comment: @DanielFischer That they are equal? Although I don't see why

Comment: Right, they are equal. Try to prove that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Isn't that the whole proof, if I use Riesz' Lemma?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. On the one hand, the Riesz lemma indeed makes short meal of the question. On the other hand, there need not exist such an $a$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I mean that I am allowed to use Riesz Lemma, which says that if $B$ were closed such an $a$ exists. Thus my thinking was that if I prove that $d(a,\overline{B})=d(a,B)$, then I am done. Is that correct or am I thinking wrongly?

Comment: It's at least mostly correct. But there's something missing, and I don't know if you're not aware of it, or just haven't mentioned it because you think it's trivial. Look over the comments here if you don't know what I mean.

Comment: @DanielFischer Do you mean the two possibilities $\overline{B}=A$ and $\overline{B}\subsetneq A$?

Comment: @DanielFischer What is the missing thing you meant?

Comment: The possibility $\overline{B} = A$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What happens in that case?

Comment: Well, what is $d(a,A)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Zero, right?

Comment: @DanielFischer So $d(a,\overline{B})=d(a,B)$ only if $B\subsetneq A$?

Comment: @DanielFischer How do I prove that $d(a,\overline{B})=d(a,B)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you please help me further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\epsilon > 1$, every $a\in A$ with $\lVert a\rVert = 1$ has the desired property, since clearly

$$d(a,B) = \inf_{b\in B} \lVert a-b\rVert \geqslant 0 > 1 - \epsilon.$$

For $0 < \epsilon \leqslant 1$, such an $a$ exists if and only if $B$ is not dense in $A$, i.e. $\overline{B} \neq A$.

That follows from the fact that $d(a,M) = d(a,\overline{M})$ for all subsets $\varnothing \neq M \subset A$ and $a \in A$, and Riesz' lemma. (The restriction $M \neq \varnothing$ is not actually necessary if one uses the [useful and natural] convention $d(a,\varnothing) = +\infty$.)

The inequality $d(a,N) \leqslant d(a,M)$ for $M \subset N$ immediately yields $d(a,\overline{M}) \leqslant d(a,M)$. For the inequality in the other direction, pick an arbitrary $x \in \overline{M}$. Then there is a sequence $(x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $x_k \in M$ for all $k$ and $x_k \to x$. By the continuity of the distance function, it follows that

$$d(a,x) = \lim_{k\to \infty} d(a,x_k) \geqslant \inf \{d(a,m) : m \in M\} = d(a,M).$$

This holds for all $x \in \overline{M}$, whence

$$d(a,\overline{M}) = \inf \{ d(a,x) : x \in \overline{M}\} \geqslant d(a,M),$$

and the equality $d(a,\overline{M}) = d(a,M)$ is established.

Now if $\overline{B} = A$, then we clearly have

$$0 \leqslant d(a,B) = d(a,\overline{B}) = d(a,A) = \inf \{ \lVert a-x\rVert : x \in A\} \leqslant \lVert a - a\rVert = 0,$$

and consequently $d(a,B) = 0 \leqslant 1-\epsilon$ for all $a \in A$, so in that case no $a\in A$ with the desired properties exists.

And if $\overline{B} \neq A$, then $\overline{B}$ is a proper closed subspace of $A$. Choose an arbitrary $a_0 \in A \setminus \overline{B}$. Since $\overline{B}$ is closed, there is an $r > 0$ such that the open ball with radius $r$ and centre $a_0$ doesn't intersect $\overline{B}$, whence $d(a_0,\overline{B}) \geqslant r > 0$. Let $a_1 = \frac{1}{d(a_0,\overline{B})}\cdot a_0$. Then $d(a_1,\overline{B}) = 1$, and by definition of the infimum, there is a $b_1 \in \overline{B}$ with $\lVert a_1 - b_1\rVert < \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}$. Then

$$a := \frac{1}{\lVert a_1 - b_1\rVert}\cdot (a_1 - b_1)$$

has the desired properties. $\lVert a\rVert = 1$ is clear, and for every $b \in \overline{B}$ we have

$$\lVert a - b\rVert = \frac{1}{\lVert a_1 - b_1\rVert}\bigl\lVert a_1 - \underbrace{(b_1 + \lVert a_1 - b_1\rVert\cdot b)}_{= b' \in \overline{B}}\bigr\rVert \geqslant \frac{1}{\lVert a_1 - b_1\rVert} d(a_1,\overline{B}) = \frac{1}{\lVert a_1 - b_1\rVert},$$

so

$$d(a,B) = d(a,\overline{B}) \geqslant \frac{1}{\lVert a_1 - b_1\rVert} > 1-\epsilon.$$

Comment: I think you mean $>$ in the last line

Comment: Yes, I do. Thanks for spotting it.